# Implementing ras:RangeLookup process in geoserver WPS petition

Tags: raster, geoserver, wps

I'm trying to implement ras:RangeLookup process in a geoserver WPS petition to download a raster changing their initial values to some input values.
This process reclassifies a continous raster into integer values defined by a set of ranges. The inputs are: the band to use (default to 0), ranges ((range min;range max)), raster value (int) and noData value (int).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    <wps:Execute version="1.0.0" service="WPS" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:wps="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:wcs="http://www.opengis.net/wcs/1.1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0/wpsAll.xsd">
    <ows:Identifier>ras:RangeLookup</ows:Identifier>
    <wps:DataInputs>
      <wps:Input>
        <ows:Identifier>coverage</ows:Identifier>
        <wps:Reference mimeType="image/tiff" xlink:href="http://geoserver/wcs" method="POST">
          <wps:Body>
            <wcs:GetCoverage xmlns:wcs="http://www.opengis.net/wcs/2.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wcs/2.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/wcs/2.0/wcsAll.xsd" service="WCS" version="2.0.1">
              <wcs:CoverageId>sentinel2_raster</wcs:CoverageId>
              <wcs:DimensionSlice>
                <wcs:Dimension>time</wcs:Dimension>
                <wcs:SlicePoint>2020-04-28T00:00:00.000Z</wcs:SlicePoint>
              </wcs:DimensionSlice>
              <wcs:format>image/geotiff</wcs:format>
            </wcs:GetCoverage>
          </wps:Body>
        </wps:Reference>
      </wps:Input>
      <wps:Input>
        <ows:Identifier>band</ows:Identifier>
        <wps:Data>
          <wps:LiteralData>0</wps:LiteralData>
        </wps:Data>
      </wps:Input>
      <wps:Input>
        <ows:Identifier>ranges</ows:Identifier>
        <wps:Data>
          <wps:LiteralData>(0.000;0.015)</wps:LiteralData>
        </wps:Data>
      </wps:Input>
      <wps:Input>
        <ows:Identifier>outputPixelValues</ows:Identifier>
        <wps:Data>
          <wps:LiteralData>20</wps:LiteralData>
        </wps:Data>
      </wps:Input><wps:Input>
        <ows:Identifier>ranges</ows:Identifier>
        <wps:Data>
          <wps:LiteralData>(0.016;0.030)</wps:LiteralData>
        </wps:Data>
      </wps:Input>
      <wps:Input>
        <ows:Identifier>outputPixelValues</ows:Identifier>
        <wps:Data>
          <wps:LiteralData>200</wps:LiteralData>
        </wps:Data>
      </wps:Input><wps:Input>
        <ows:Identifier>ranges</ows:Identifier>
        <wps:Data>
          <wps:LiteralData>(0.031;0.100)</wps:LiteralData>
        </wps:Data>
      </wps:Input>
      <wps:Input>
        <ows:Identifier>outputPixelValues</ows:Identifier>
        <wps:Data>
          <wps:LiteralData>2000</wps:LiteralData>
        </wps:Data>
      </wps:Input>
      <wps:Input>
        <ows:Identifier>noData</ows:Identifier>
        <wps:Data>
          <wps:LiteralData>0</wps:LiteralData>
        </wps:Data>
      </wps:Input>
    </wps:DataInputs>
    <wps:ResponseForm>
      <wps:RawDataOutput mimeType="image/tiff">
        <ows:Identifier>reclassified</ows:Identifier>
      </wps:RawDataOutput>
    </wps:ResponseForm>
    </wps:Execute>
```

gdalinfo:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: sentinel2_raster.tiff 
Size is 376, 1221 
Coordinate System is: 
PROJCRS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 21S", 
   BASEGEOGCRS["WGS 84", 
       DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984", 
           ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563, 
               LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]], 
       PRIMEM["Greenwich",0, 
           ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
       ID["EPSG",4326]], 
   CONVERSION["UTM zone 21S", 
       METHOD["Transverse Mercator", 
           ID["EPSG",9807]], 
       PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0, 
           ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433], 
           ID["EPSG",8801]], 
       PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",-57, 
           ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433], 
           ID["EPSG",8802]], 
       PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",0.9996, 
           SCALEUNIT["unity",1], 
           ID["EPSG",8805]], 
       PARAMETER["False easting",500000, 
           LENGTHUNIT["metre",1], 
           ID["EPSG",8806]], 
       PARAMETER["False northing",10000000, 
           LENGTHUNIT["metre",1], 
           ID["EPSG",8807]]], 
   CS[Cartesian,2], 
       AXIS["(E)",east, 
           ORDER[1], 
           LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]], 
       AXIS["(N)",north, 
           ORDER[2], 
           LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]], 
   USAGE[ 
       SCOPE["unknown"], 
       AREA["World - S hemisphere - 60°W to 54°W - by country"], 
       BBOX[-80,-60,0,-54]], 
   ID["EPSG",32721]] 
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 1,2 
Origin = (363330.000000000000000,6684530.000000000000000) 
Pixel Size = (10.000000000000000,-10.000000000000000) 
Metadata: 
 AREA_OR_POINT=Area 
 TIFFTAG_RESOLUTIONUNIT=1 (unitless) 
 TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION=1 
 TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION=1 
Image Structure Metadata: 
 INTERLEAVE=BAND 
Corner Coordinates: 
Upper Left ( 363330.000, 6684530.000) ( 58d24'59.16"W, 29d57'44.87"S) 
Lower Left ( 363330.000, 6672320.000) ( 58d25' 4.80"W, 30d 4'21.44"S) 
Upper Right ( 367090.000, 6684530.000) ( 58d22'38.90"W, 29d57'46.36"S) 
Lower Right ( 367090.000, 6672320.000) ( 58d22'44.39"W, 30d 4'22.93"S) 
Center     ( 365210.000, 6678425.000) ( 58d23'51.81"W, 30d 1' 3.91"S) 
Band 1 Block=384x512 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Gray 
 NoData Value=0\
```

The problem is that it works only with values lower than 100. If I use values greater than 100, when I open the file with QGIS values are negative (-12 or -25 are some examples). Sometimes it works with values greater than 100 but most of the time it fails. Maybe the error could be related with the raster initial values.

Does anyone know what is happening?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Can you fill in the actual values that you are using and the `gdalinfo` output describing your tiff,

Comment: I edited the question with the actual info. @IanTurton